# “Vom Frühstück aufstehen”

Tags: grammar, meaning, preposition

I have read the following statement in a German book:

> Ich stehe vom Frühstück auf.

I couldn’t understand the purpose of using *von* here, not even the whole meaning. Is it to mean: “I wake up for the breakfast”? Or “I complete the breakfast”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

»Aufstehen« is a separable verb that means »to stand up« or »to get up«. You use it whenever you change your position form not-standing (i.e. laying, sitting, ...) to standing.

> Ich wachte auf und bin gleich darauf *aufgestanden*.
>   I woke up and immediately *got up*.

See: »Aufwachen« (to wake up) is not the same as »aufstehen« (to get up). You can wake up and stay laying in bed for hours without getting up.

> Tom saß bis 9:00 Uhr auf seinem Koffer und *stand* erst *auf* als der Zug ankam.
>   Tom sat on his suitcase until 9:00 o'clock and *stood up* when the train arrived.
>
> Anna stand vom Frühstück auf.
>   Anna stood up from breakfast.

Having breakfast is something you normally do sitting. So when you have finished breakfast and then stand up, you stand up from breakfast.

Comment: Then "von" is used with "aufstehen" always to mean "of".

Answer (score 0):

Hubert provided a nice overview over the meaning of *aufstehen*. Once you understood that, it should be easier to understand the meaning the preposition *vom* conveys: You are getting up *from* the breakfast (so you are leaving the table).

The verb *aufstehen* is the same regardless of whether you’re getting up from the table or getting out of bed (or getting up off the floor/settee). Only the preposition is able to show at which part of the movement the breakfast actually was and therefore where you are going.

> Ich stehe zum Frühstück auf.

This sentence is not as idiomatic as the other (I probably wouldn’t say it) but it would be understood as getting up from something *to go to get/eat breakfast.*

> Ich stehe im Frühstück auf.

This sentence is rather weird if a human says it, but a fly that got stuck in your jam could have finally managed to get up and then say that it is now getting up inside the breakfast (on the table).

> Ich stehe vom Frühstück auf.

This is the usual case; you are leaving (*von*) the breakfast. So you are leaving the table.

More options are possible but probably even less likely than the unlikely one in the middle, so I am omitting them here.